# Characterizing the unique solution to a matrix equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-decomposition, matrix-rank

**Setup** Let $\Pi$ be an $n\times n$ matrix where each row sums to one. Let $\mathcal Y$ be an eigenvector of $\Pi'$ such that
\begin{equation*}
 \Pi' \mathcal Y=\mathcal Y
\end{equation*}

Denote $\Psi$ as the diagonal matrix whose diagonal is  the vector $\mathcal Y$.

Let $n\times n$ matrix $A$ satisfies the following equation
\begin{equation*}
  (\mathbf I-\Pi) A    = I-\Psi ^{-1} (\Pi')^{-1}\Psi   
\end{equation*}
where $I$ is an identity matrix. Note that the matrix $  (\mathbf I-\Pi)$ is not full rank, and there are multiple matrices $A$ satisfying the equation above. Note, we assume $\Pi'$ is invertible and $\Pi \neq I$.

**Question** Let $M$ be an $n\times n$ matrix  such that each row of $M$ sums to one. We want to show that for any choice of $A$,
\begin{equation*}
(I-M) A =D
\end{equation*}
where $D$ only depends on $\Pi$ and $M$, and it does not depend on the choice of $A$.

**Note** We have tested this claim numerically, but we are unable to find a way to prove this or characterize the matrix $D$ explicitly in terms of only $\Pi$ and $M$.

Comment: $\Pi'$ is the transpose of $\Pi$ ? Why $Pi'$ should be invertible ?

Comment: Yes \Pi' is the transpose, and we assumed it was invertible. I clarified the question, sorry for the confusion. Any hints on how we can prove this would be very welcome.

Comment: Your hypothesis fails for the trivial case where $\Pi=I$, the identity matrix.  In this case, $A$ can be any matrix whatsoever, and then it is clearly not true that $(I-M)A$ is constant for a fixed generic $M$ and totally arbitrary $A$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. We meant to exclude the case $\Pi=I$. I edited the question to make that clear.